# Problem in Dotnetnuke to create module project

Tags: iis, dotnetnuke

I am new to the Dotnetnuke framework and I have problem to create module project.

I have VS2012, SQL 2008R2, IIS7.5, Win7, DNN_Platform_07.04.00 and I installed DotNetNuke Project Templates VSIX v2.5.

When I make a new project:

[image]

I get this error:

[image]

Any idea why I get this error and how to fix it?

Comment: Watch video "How to setup the Environment and Template to develop modules on DotNetNuke 7".  http://www.dnnhero.com/Premium/Tutorial/ArticleID/196/How-to-setup-the-Environment-and-Template-to-develop-modules-on-DotNetNuke-7-Part-1-3

Answer (score 0):

Go to IIS Manager, select the site (in my case it's dnndev.me) under the Sites node in the tree. In the Actions panel, see the item "Edit Site" Bindings...
Click Bindings... and ensure Host Name is dnndev.me and not www.dnndev.me